# Windows 8 screen stays solid color. Can't log in

Tags: windows-8

I left my computer unattended for a while, and I wasn't at all surprised to see that the computer had went black.

I move the mouse, and the lock screen is present. Complete with current time, and up-to-date mail information.

I click on the lock screen, and it animates up and out of the way, and it leaves the screen blank, except for the solid color that I chose at installation (dark blue).

Windows does not resume, the password screen does not come up. After some time of waiting, the lock screen reappears (no slide-in animation, but it might very quickly fade in, I can't tell).

I can't log in, I can't use the computer. Hot corners do nothing. ctrl+alt+del does nothing.

What should I do? How can I prevent this problem from recurring?

Comment: Rebooting allows me to use the computer again.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something is causing your screen to hang when the lock screen disappears, and considering it's windows 8 it's most likely a bug that just hasn't been patched yet. Your best bet would to reinstall or if your willing to wait a while contact microsoft about it, they most likely have a fix for it and if not no doubt others are experiencing it as well and one will be made in time.

Comment: Hmm, that seems a little strong of a statement to make. Rebooting seems to make the problem go away (temporarily?)